# Difference between "a" and "the"

Tags: grammar, articles

Is there a difference between **a** and **the** in the following context? As an English speaker do they both sound natural?

What is a/the computer?

- **A/the** computer is an automatic electronic machine that convert raw data into useful information.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is pretty much nonexistent.

*A* would be used in response to the question *What's a computer*?, simply because of maintaining parallelism. (It's very unlikely anybody would ask *What's the computer?*)

*The* might be used when the statement is simply volunteered unasked for. Or it could actually be discussing a specific, identified computer. (However, that's doubtful given the general meaning of what comes after.)

In both cases, it's likely that *computer* is being used in a general, non-specific way, without any sense of a countable noun.

---

However, it's probably more common to use neither version, instead phrasing it in the plural:

> Computers are automatic electronic machines that convert raw data into useful information.